# Spring Boot doesn't pick the values from application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot-starter-web latest version 2.2.6.RELEASE. But my application always returns null for a variable with @value annotation.

My build.gradle,

```
plugins {
  id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '2.1.0'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
  id 'eclipse'
  id 'idea'
  id 'maven-publish'
}

jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'my-project'
    project.version =  '1.0.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '+'
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:+') {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:+")
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.8.0'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.8.0'
    implementation group: 'io.kubernetes', name: 'client-java', version: '+'
    implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-dataproc', version: '+'

    implementation(project(':my-project-1')) {
        exclude group: 'org.yaml'
    }

    implementation project(':my-project2')
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:unchecked'
    options.deprecation = true
}
```

My Java code,

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

    @Value("${dataproc.host}")
    private static String dataprocEndpoint;
```

My application.yml

```
dataproc:
  host: dataproc.googleapis.com:443
```

My Application.java,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class Application {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    private transient String PATTERNS_TO_HIDE = "^/(?!error|autoconfig|beans|profile|info|health|pause|env|refresh|resume|restart|actuator|dump|mappings|trace|metrics|heapdump|archaius|configprops|features|liquibase|loggers|auditevents).*$";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfoBuilder().license("Proprietary").title("My Application")
                .description("My Application").build();

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex(PATTERNS_TO_HIDE)).build().pathMapping("/").apiInfo(apiInfo)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET, newArrayList(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(500)
                        .message("500 message").responseModel(new ModelRef("Error")).build()));
    }
}
```

Always getting null when I starting the server,
dataprocEndpoint: null

What configuration am I missing here?

Kindly provide your inputs here.

Answer (score 2):

1. surround your property in quotes:

   dataproc:
     host: 'dataproc.googleapis.com:443'

Yml processor interprets your config property name as dataproc.host.dataproc.googleapis.com.443

2. Remove static from your field declaration.

   @Value("${dataproc.host}")
   private String dataprocEndpoint;

Static fields are initialized with class load. Spring bean post processors can’t inject values at so early phase. You can use setter injection if you want to inject value to static field anyway.

Ref https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-inject-a-value-into-static-variables/

Comment: Still am getting null even after updating with single quotes

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: It's working after creating the bean class instead of instance class.

Comment: Cool! Glad to help you.

Comment: That's right. I removed static keyword.